# How to use random to generate different string answers for a game

Tags: python, random

When I call computer.guess(). It doesn't generate a R, S, or P like I thought it would. Any hints on what I did wrong? I do have random imported into the script and when I run it in the command line. It does not return anything back to me

```
class Computer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.winning = True
        self.game_over = False

    def guess(self):
        if random.randint(0,2) == 0:
            return 'R'
            print('Computer chose R')
        elif random.randint(0,2) == 1:
            return 'P'
            print('Computer chose P')
        else:
            return 'S'
            print('Computer chose S')

    def win(self):

        if guess == 'S' and player.guess == 'P':
            self.winning
            print('Computer is the winner!')
        if guess == 'R' and player.guess == 'S':
            self.winning
            print('Computer is the winner!')
        if guess == 'P' and player.guess == 'R':
            self.winning
            print('Computer is the winner!')

    def computer_lose(self):

        if player.win == winning:
            print('Computer has lost')
            self.game_over = True
            self.winning = False
```

Comment: Where and how are you calling any of these functions? Please provide a proper [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

It will keep generating a new random number each time you call it. Also you should return as the the last thing you do.

```
    def guess(self):
        x = random.randint(0,2)
        if x == 0:
            print('Computer chose R')
            return('R')
        elif x == 1:
            print('Computer chose P')
            return('P')
        else:
            print('Computer chose S')
            return('S')
```

Also are you sure that you have called it

Answer (score 0):

You are drawing multiple times and hence `guess()` will not provide a uniform distribution across `R`, `S` or `P`.
Also, you are `return`ing your value before the code ever reaches the `print()` statement.
You should call `print()` before `return`.

Try this instead:

```
...

    def guess(self):
        n = random.randint(0, 2)
        choice = 'RPS'[n]
        print(f'Computer chose {choice}')
        return choice
```

---

Also, `win()` is excessively verbose and the `self.winning` statement has no effect (did you forget some assignment?).
You could rewrite it as something similar to:

```
...
    def win(self):
        if guess == player.guess:
            print('Computer is the winner!')
            self.winning = False  # I guess?
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify this a lot by using random.choice to select between P, S and R.  and also by using a dictionary to determine winning conditions:

preparation:

```
import random
outcomes = { "PP":0, "RR":0, "SS":0, "PR":1, "RS":1, "SP":1, "RP":2, "SR":2, "PS":2 }
results  = ["Draw","Player wins","Computer Wins"]
```

output:

```
player   = random.choice("PSR") # input("Select R,P,S: ")
computer = random.choice("PSR")
result   = outcomes[player+computer]

print("Player chose",player)
print("Computer chose",computer)
print(results[result])

Player chose S
Computer chose P
Player wins
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this

```
def guess(self):
    mydict = {0: "R", 1: "P", 2: "S"}
    return mydict[random.randint(0, 2)]
```